# Irreduciblity of polynomial in $\Bbb Q[x]$

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to prove that $x^5 + 16$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$. (Hint: Consider $(x-1)^5 + 16$)

Not sure how to use the hint, thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Expand $(x-1)^5+16$ and use Eisenstein's criterion.

Answer (score 2):

**Second hint:** $x^5+16$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ if, (and only if), $(x-1)^5+16$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Amy No problem.